# Can't send mail via SSL or TLS using SMTP using Javamail

Tags: java, ssl, smtp

Happy New Year!

I'm working on a application where the user gets an email whenever a particular trigger occurs.

This is the function that I'm using to send Email:

```
public static void sendEmail(String host, String port, String useSSL, String useTLS, String useAuth, String user, String password, String subject, String content, String type, String recipients)
            throws NoSuchProviderException, AddressException, MessagingException  {
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", port);        
        if (useSSL != null && !useSSL.equals("false") && useSSL.equals("true")) {
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", useSSL);
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                    "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);

        }
        if (useTLS != null && !useTLS.equals("false") && useTLS.equals("true")) {
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", useTLS);
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "true");
        }   
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", useAuth);
        props.setProperty("mail.from", user);  
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", user);
        props.setProperty("mail.password", password);

        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(props.getProperty("mail.smtp.user"), props
                        .getProperty("mail.password"));
            }
        });   

        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        message.setHeader("Subject", subject);
        message.setContent(content, type);

        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(recipients, ";");
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String recipient = tokenizer.nextToken();
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(recipient));
        }

        transport.connect();
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();
```

Odd enough, whenever I try to run the above code with main method it'd send the email for both SSL and TLS protocols successfully.

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try {
            Notifier.sendEmail("smtp.gmail.com", "587", "false", "true", "true","sender_email@gmail.com", "testpassword", "CHECKING SETTINGS", "CHECKING EMAIL FUNCTIONALITY", "text/html", "cc_email@gmail.com");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

But it fails whenever I try to run the same code through my web application.

Sending it via SSL throws this error:

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
jvm 1    | 530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 f12sm88286300pat.20 - gsmtp
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    |  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2057)
```

Sending it via TLS throws this error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
jvm 1    |   nested exception is:
jvm 1    |  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
jvm 1    |  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

EDIT1:

Here's the tpl file from front end

```
<div class="label1"><h3 class="label">Host:</h3></div>
     <div class="field1"><input type="text" class="input1" name="host" size="20" value="$HOST$"></div>
         <div class="port"><h3 class="label">Port:</h3></div>
         <div class="fieldport"><input type="text" class="fieldport" name="port" size="5" value="$PORT$"></div>
         <div class="ssl">
                <input type="radio" name="sslEnable" value="$SSLENABLE$">
                    Enable SSL?
         </div>
         <div class="tls">
                <input type="radio" name="tlsEnable" value="$TLSENABLE$">
                    Enable TLS?
         </div>
         <div class="auth">
                <input type="checkbox" name="auth"$AUTH$>
                    Enable Authentication?
         </div>            
     <div class="label2"><h3 class="label">User:</h3></div>
     <div class="field2"><input type="text" class="input1" name="user" size="20" value="$USER$"></div>
     <div class="label3"><h3 class="label">Password:</h3></div>
     <div class="field3"><input type="password" class="input1" name="password" size="20" value="$PASSWORD$"></div>
     <div class="label4"><h3 class="label">Recipient(s):</h3></div>
     <div class="field4"><input type="text" class="input1" name="recipients" size="50" value="$RECIPIENTS$"></div>
```

The values gets saved in a configuration file which looks like this:

```
host=smtp.gmail.com
port=587
ssl=false
tls=true
auth=true
user=send_user_email@gmail.com
password=O0UbYboDfVFRaiA=
recipients=cc_user_email@gmail.com
trigger1=false
attempt=0
trigger2=false
percent=5
anyOrAll=ANY
trigger3=true
format=HTML
trigger4=true
trigger5=true
```

EDIT2:

```
public static void sendEmail(String message)
      throws NoSuchProviderException, AddressException, MessagingException
  {
    if (message == null || message.trim().equals("")) return;

    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
    content.append(getHeader());
    content.append(message);
    content.append(getFooter());
    String format = NotifyProps.getFormat();
    String type = "text/plain";
    if (format.equals(NotifyProps.HTML)) type = "text/html";

    sendEmail(NotifyProps.getHost(), NotifyProps.getPort(), Boolean.toString(NotifyProps.getUseAuth()), Boolean.toString(NotifyProps.getUseSSL()), Boolean.toString(NotifyProps.getUseTLS()),NotifyProps.getUser(), NotifyProps.getPassword(),
              "Transaction Processor Auto Notification", content.toString(), type,
              NotifyProps.getRecipients())
  }
```

This is the the class that sets and gets the properties:

https://codeshare.io/5G8ki

Thank you.

Comment: What surprises me is that you say it works in the command-line test. You should be setting `mail.smtp.socketFactory.class` to `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory` even with TLS, not just SSL.    
But unrelated to that, I would suggest you use Yoda conditions to check for string constants like `"true".equals(sslStr)`. It's null-safe and has less clutter.

Answer (score 2):

Altough your code looks ok, there is at least one big problem. **You are trying to use the same port (587) for both TLS and SSL.** I am not sure about TLS, but the SSL code should work IF you would send your request to port 465. As written [here (google FAQ)](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en):

> configuring your SMTP server on port 465 (with SSL) and port 587 (with TLS)[...]

They have their own specific ports. The error you get for SSL:

```
Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

Is your client not understanding the fact that it received a non-SSL encoded response (due to the TLS port not implementing SSL).

Comment: I'm not using the same port for both the protocols.
I'm using 465 for SSL and 587 for TLS.

Comment: Could you show us the web code that is actually producing the error? You included the main method version, but that already works. Based on the errormessage you *are* trying to initiate SSL connection on a TLS port. Could be something wrong with your parameterlist in your webapp?

Comment: And how is that configuration being read? The frontend code is not so much relevant as the part where you load this config. These config entries (like port) eventually reach the `sendMail` function. It would be good to see if they do arrive properly.

Comment: The website you used for your last link is returning HTTP 522, so I could not check that. Is it possible to log the parameters in your webapp to show the exact values it get? There might be conflicting parameters being read, or returning default values, cached results... All sorts of errors can lead to having the wrong port passed in the end.

Answer (score 1):

We are having few more properties set for TLS

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

For Auth use smtps instead of smtp

```
props.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", useAuth);
```

While Getting the Transport

```
session.getTransport("smtps");
```

Again pass the host email and password while connecting

```
transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "user@email", "password");
```

For debugging

```
session.setDebug(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code it works for me.

```
public void sendEmail(){

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("senderEmail@gmail.com","secret");
                }
            });

            try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from-email@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("to-email@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("This is testing message");
            message.setText("Hi this is testing email....not spam");

        Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("email successfully sent..");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently, there is an update security in gmail. You must allow the option "Allow less secure application access" in the page https://myaccount.google.com/security?pli=1. Then you can send mails from your account without problem

Answer (score 0):

[simple-java-mail](http://www.simple-java-mail.org) has a simple enum you can use to indicate SSL or TLS. You don't need to worry about the correct properties that way:

```
Email email = new Email();

(...)

new Mailer("smtp.gmail.com", 25, "your user", "your password", TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS).sendMail(email);
new Mailer("smtp.gmail.com", 587, "your user", "your password", TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS).sendMail(email);
new Mailer("smtp.gmail.com", 465, "your user", "your password", TransportStrategy.SMTP_SSL).sendMail(email);
```

If you have two-factor login turned on, you need to generate an [application specific password](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) from your Google account to make this example work.