# Spring-Boot migration from 2.7.x to 3.1.x breaks mail sending

Tags: spring-boot, smtp

After we migrate one of our service to Spring-Boot 3.1.1, we see errors when sending an email, that did not raised before.

This error raised since the migration, and is not related to any certificate issue on the SMTP server (checked, and if using previous version, it works again).

We use Java17 and spring-boot-starter-parent v3.1.1.

```
2023-08-18 11:31:05.560 ERROR 78703 --- [ntContainer#0-1] c.d.s.portal.service.EmailService        : An error has occurred while sending the mail 

org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed. Failed messages: jakarta.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException: Can't verify identity of server: my-smtp-server
Caused by: jakarta.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2189)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:766)
    at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:518)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:437)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't verify identity of server: my-smtp-server
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.checkServerIdentity(SocketFetcher.java:699)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:636)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:555)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2184)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

I already tried some suggestions from following posts

- [Sending email via Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74694051/sending-email-via-spring-boot)
- [Can't send mail via SSL or TLS using SMTP using Javamail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34671474/cant-send-mail-via-ssl-or-tls-using-smtp-using-javamail)

I even tried to change the use of `org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender` to `org.springframework.mail.MailSender`

With no results, as the same error appears again and again.

Do you have any idea why migration to SB v3.x makes this server identification fails ?
We had [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76407443/spring-config-server-ssh-git-connection-through-proxy-since-boot-3-x-is-failing) for another service, and now both seems linked to a change of SSL use inside SB (or maybe not).

Comment: Issue has been solved changing the host in our configuration to use an url on which we retrieve the correct SSL certificate.

What I do not explain, is why changing Spring-boot version the SSL check do not work anymore, while it did before and nothing changed on the SMTP server we used.

If somebody knows ...

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue. As I checked `mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity` was `false` by default. Now with 3.1 it looks default is `true`. I set it false again and worked. Of course it's not safe against man-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and needed some more digging to know how to tackle the problem. It all boils down to the following - in our case:

- Spring Boot 2.7.13 uses jakarta.mail 1.6.7 from com.sun.mail (maven dependency)
- Spring Boot 3.1.6 uses jakarta.mail 1.1.0 from org.eclipse.angus

So in case you get confused that the version number *decreases* - that's because jakarta.mail is now developed by org.eclipse.angus (and, apparently, they resetted the version number).

And here is the difference: Version 1.6.7 (the old one) has the following code

```
SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket: boolean idCheck = PropUtil.getBooleanProperty(props, prefix + ".ssl.checkserveridentity", false);
```

Whereas version 1.1.0 (the new one) initializes it as follows:

```
SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket: boolean idCheck = PropUtil.getBooleanProperty(props, prefix + ".ssl.checkserveridentity", true);
```

This means: if you use Spring's `JavaMailSenderImpl` you can set the property `spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity=false`. But if you use the plain jakarta mail api, you will need to resort to setting `mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity` to `false`.