# Jakarta Mail: Can't verify identity of server

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send e-mails in a Spring Boot application and get this exception

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed. Failed messages: jakarta.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException: Can't verify identity of server: example.com; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: jakarta.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException: Can't verify identity of server:
```

I already tried several answers from SO and my configuration looks like this:

```
spring.mail.host=example.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=noreply@example.com
spring.mail.password=7Wdz@o75
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust=example.com
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

Any help is appreciated.

When I run it with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` I see:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|91|http-nio-8081-exec-4|2023-08-30 11:47:15.614 CEST|null:-1|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|91|http-nio-8081-exec-4|2023-08-30 11:47:15.778 CEST|null:-1|duplex close of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|91|http-nio-8081-exec-4|2023-08-30 11:47:15.779 CEST|null:-1|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|91|http-nio-8081-exec-4|2023-08-30 11:47:15.779 CEST|null:-1|close the SSL connection (initiative)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|91|http-nio-8081-exec-4|2023-08-30 11:47:15.780 CEST|null:-1|close inbound of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|91|http-nio-8081-exec-4|2023-08-30 11:47:15.783 CEST|null:-1|SSLSocket duplex close failed. Debug info only. Exception details: (
"throwable" : {
  java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.shutdownInput(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.bruteForceCloseInput(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.duplexCloseOutput(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.close(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.checkServerIdentity(SocketFetcher.java:698)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:636)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:555)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2184)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:766)
    at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:518)
```

Comment: What is the host of the mail server and does it have a proper cert?

Comment: It has a Let's encrypt certificate. The host is a Linux server.

Comment: So are you running your own mail server and if so, how did you install the certificate on it?

Comment: The server uses Plesk which has a Let's encrypt plugin.

Comment: Could be that the setup is interfering with the proper resolution of the host. I'd suggest running with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`. That's from memory so check that if there's no effect

Comment: @g00se I've added the output of debug ssl

Comment: You've added the *partial* output by the looks

Comment: That's all I see. After this, I see the exception that's in the question in the beginning

Comment: There should be a lot more. Run it at the command line, ending with `>ssl.log 2>&1` and post that file formatted as code

Comment: Nope. Only these lines

Comment: Can you connect and send mail properly with ssl with a regular mail client connecting to that server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the default value for `mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity` has changed from `false` to `true` with Spring Boot 3.1. Setting it back fixed the problem for me. But this should not be the long-term solution.

So in your case this should do the trick:

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity=false
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77022083/2083900.

Comment: Is there any vulnerability introduced by this

Comment: @DavidKariuki If you upgrade to Spring Boot >= 3.1 and run into this problem now and not before, then at least you are not introducing any new security problems by disabling this value.
However, the occurrence of the error is of course a sign that something is going wrong when establishing the connection. It does not necessarily have to be a MitM attack, but can also be a misconfiguration of the SMTP host, which should be corrected sooner if possible. Chapter 2.4 of [RFC 2595](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2595.txt) requires this check.